# How to implement GCM sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken) in android client

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have write a server using node.js, and I have no idea how can I send the registration token from an android client to this server?

```
public void onTokenRefresh() {
// Get updated InstanceID token.
String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

// TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
```

More precisely, what should I write to implement sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken) and how can I receive it on my server?

Comment: You probably looking for web service. you can send this token using HTTP.

Comment: So there is no built-in functions?

Comment: I don't think there is any built-in function for that as long as I know.

Comment: Confirming what @MayankPandya said, the `sendRegistrationToServer()` should be an implementation specific to the developer. How they send the token to their designated database.